# Xamarin Forms trying to make content button

Tags: android, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to do a content button with only shared code (no native project code, so no renderer and no effect).
To do this I created a ContentView with a classic button as following:
(To keep it simple I added only a Label as the content)

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button"
            Released="button_Released"/>

    <Label x:Name="text"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           InputTransparent="True"/>
</Grid>
```

I also created a text bindable property like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(ContentButton), propertyChanged: TextChanged);

public string Text
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}

private static void TextChanged(object sender, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var button = sender as ContentButton;
    button.text.Text = newValue as string;
}
```

And next, I use my ContentButton as the following:

```
<controls:ContentButton Text="Some text"/>
```

The button is displayed correctly. But when I click it, it seems to pass in front of my label and from that moment the text is no longer visible.
The only workaround I found to fix this is to place this code in the released event of the button:

```
await Task.Delay(200);
text.IsVisible = false;
text.IsVisible = true;
```

But obviously this is not a suitable solution.

This issue appears on Android 9 with Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1687

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that the Button cover the Label when you click Button, why not add Text in Button?

Comment: Hi, because I have simplified for the example but my final idea is to put something other than text. So I can’t use the Text property of the Button. And I also wanted to keep it simple and take advantage of all the logic, especially visual, that already exists for the Button control. So I don't need to go through a renderer or an effect

Comment: I find one workaround, changing Button background as transparent, then you always can see text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I close this question according to the comment of @Cherry BU.
I put a transparent background color on the button and I added a BoxView below to manage the real background color and the possible CornerRadius.
Because I use Material Visual, I also created a custom renderer to remove the default button shadow like this:

```
class ExtendedMaterialButtonRenderer : MaterialButtonRenderer
{
    public ExtendedMaterialButtonRenderer(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.StateListAnimator = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I also added a scale animation on my ContentButton control on the Pressed and Released events of the button.

I mark this question as answered but I remain open to other solutions if something has a better solution to offer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relays on the `propertyChanged` event, you are passing an object as sender when the right property is `BindableObject`.

This would be the right way:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Text),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(ContentButton),
    propertyChanged: TextChanged
);

private static void TextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var contentButton = (ContentButton)bindable;

    contentButton.text.Text = (string)newValue;
}
```

Also, always remember to user direct casting when you're working with BindableProperties because if something goes wrong it will throw an exception, casting with the `as` operator could assing null and eventually throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Hi @FabriBertani, tanks for reply. i can’t try it now but it seems it’s not the problem. My text is correctly displayed but it disappears when i click on the button. Also, thanks for your advise about cast

Comment: I tried to make your suggested changes but it doesn't fix my issue.